# How to use FuncAnimation in a Time Series plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I'm simulating a sensor sendig data to one server, where it saves the data value (random from 1 to 3) and the full date (Y-m-d H:m:s) to a database.

My plot program is accessing the database and plotting data as it enters. At first I thought it wouldn't work, but It has as long as I plot my x Axis is not date time (So it basically plots if I use the "strings" of dates as ticks on this axis)

I have now changed a bit, have a functional "plot area" of a times series, but the points are not entering my plot automatically anymore. If I rerun the program, the points appear.

My code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from dateutil import parser
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import sqlite3
from mpldatacursor import datacursor
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,4))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)


def animate(i):

    datas = []
    dates = []

    con = sqlite3.connect('edgedb')
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT data, timestamp FROM edgedata')
    data = c.fetchall()


    for row in data:
        datas.append(pd.to_datetime(row[1], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').time())
        dates.append(float(row[0]))


    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot_date(x = datas, y = dates, color = 'darkgreen', ls='-', marker='o')
    ax1.set_xticks(datas)

    plt.xticks(rotation=60, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    #ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    ax1.grid(True)

    plt.ion()


def print_coords(**kwargs):
    return 'Valor medido : {y:.6f} às {x:s}'.format(y=kwargs['y'],                                                 x=mdates.num2date(kwargs['x']).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

datacursor(ax1, formatter = print_coords)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)


plt.show()
```

The code worked fine without the use of the parameter i in the animate function, and I've already tried ploting an empty plot (line, = ax1.plot_dates([],[]) ) and then setting the data inside the animate function (line.set_data(x,y) ), but with no success so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you will have problems plotting `time`, instead try to plot the full datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it seems I found a way that put it to work.

Changed the xaxis locator to:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
```

And voilà, it updates each time the database is updated!

Thanks